# MySQL order by field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi im trying to order domain data using their status. As you might know, domain status DOM_EXP or DOM_DAKT applies before domain hits DOM_HELD therefore i dont care whitch one of this status has a domain before it became DOM_HELD

How can i order this data? Using select provided below i only achieve that DOM_DAKT is behing DOM_EXP but i want it to be somewhere in between, ordered by exp_date

```
SELECT domain_id, status, exp_date 
FROM domains 
ORDER BY 
field (status, 'DOM_DEL', 'DOM_HELD', 'DOM_EXP', 'DOM_DAKT'), 
exp_date ASC;

+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| domain_id | status   | exp_date            |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|         2 | DOM_DEL  | 2012-02-02 10:47:33 |
|         4 | DOM_HELD | 2012-02-02 10:47:38 |
|         5 | DOM_HELD | 2012-02-02 10:47:40 |
|         7 | DOM_HELD | 2012-02-02 10:47:44 |
|         1 | DOM_EXP  | 2012-02-02 10:47:27 |
|         3 | DOM_EXP  | 2012-02-02 10:47:35 |
|         6 | DOM_EXP  | 2012-02-02 10:47:42 |
|        54 | DOM_DAKT | 2012-02-02 10:47:39 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

the result have to be like this

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| domain_id | status   | exp_date            |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|         2 | DOM_DEL  | 2012-02-02 10:47:33 |
|         4 | DOM_HELD | 2012-02-02 10:47:38 |
|         5 | DOM_HELD | 2012-02-02 10:47:40 |
|         7 | DOM_HELD | 2012-02-02 10:47:44 |
|         1 | DOM_EXP  | 2012-02-02 10:47:27 |
|         3 | DOM_EXP  | 2012-02-02 10:47:35 |
|        54 | DOM_DAKT | 2012-02-02 10:47:39 |
|         6 | DOM_EXP  | 2012-02-02 10:47:42 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: is the last row of expected result meant to be `DOM_DAKT`?

Comment: @BloodyWorld: no on DOM_EXP and DOM_DAKT should only apply order by exp_date since they are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order first by "rank" of status where `DOM_EXP` and `DOM_DAKT` are considered to be of equal rank. Then order by `EXP_DATE` within each "rank" of status

```
SELECT domain_id, status, exp_date 
FROM domains 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = 'DOM_DEL'  THEN 1
              WHEN status = 'DOM_HELD' THEN 2
              WHEN status = 'DOM_EXP'  THEN 3
              WHEN status = 'DOM_DAKT' THEN 3 -- EXP and DAKT are "of equal rank"
END,
EXP_DATE
```

Look at the `CASE` expression as a mapping `status` => `ordering rank`

Answer (score 0):

Simply drop `DROP_EXP` and `DOM_DAKT` from the statement.

```
SELECT domain_id, status, exp_date 
FROM domains 
ORDER BY 
field (status, 'DOM_DEL', 'DOM_HELD'), 
exp_date ASC;
```

That's assuming that `DOM_EXP` and `DOM_DAKT` are the only other statuses.

Comment: i cannot do that because there are other statuses, see Lukas Eder answen